# how to write a default iterator to a generic list?

Tags: c++, list, generics

i am writing this code a generic list , now in this generic list i did a class for iterator that helds two parameters : one is a pointer to the list he points to .
and the other one points to the element in the list he points to ..

now i need to write an insert function that inserts a new element to a given list , with the following rules :: where i insert a new node to the list, and in this function if the iterator poiints to the end of the list the we add the new node to the end of the list else we insert the node one place before the node that the iterator currently points to , and if the iteratot points to a different node then thats an error .

now i want the iterator to be defoult so in case in the tests someone called the function with one parameter i want the iterator to be equal to the end element of the list.
the function end i wrote it inside of the list.
now in the insert function i did that but i get this error :

> cannot call member function "List::iterator List::end()"without object
>   .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Exceptions.h"

template <class T>
class List {

public:
    List();
    List(const List&);
    ~List();
    List<T>& operator=(const List& list);
    template <class E>
    class ListNode {
        private:
             ListNode(const E& t, ListNode<E> *next): data(new E(t)), next(next){}
             ~ListNode(){delete data;}
             E* data;
             ListNode<E> *next;
        public:
            friend class List<E>;
            friend class Iterator;
            E getData() const{
               return *(this->data);
            }
            ListNode<E>* getNext() const{
               return this->next;
            }
            };
    class Iterator {
        const List<T>* list;
        int index;
        ListNode<T>* current;
        Iterator(const List<T>* list, int index): list(list),
                index(index),current(NULL){
            int cnt=index;
            while (cnt > 0) {
                current = current->next;
                cnt--;
                    }
        }
        friend class List<T>;
        friend class ListNode<T>;
    public:
       // more functions for iterator
    };
    Iterator begin() const ;
    Iterator end() const;
    void insert(const T& data, Iterator iterator=end());//here i get the error
    void remove(Iterator iterator);
    class Predicate{
    private:
      T target;
    public:
      Predicate(T i) : target(i) {}
      bool operator()(const T& i) const {
        return i == target;
      }
    };
    Iterator find(const Predicate& predicate);
    class Compare{
    private:
      T target;
    public:
      Compare(T i) : target(i) {}
      bool operator()(const T& i) const {
        return i < target;
      }
    };
    bool empty() const;
    int compareLinkedList(ListNode<T> *node1,  ListNode<T> *node2);

private:
   ListNode<T> *head;
   ListNode<T> *tail;
int size;
};
```

any help would be amazing ! cause i don't know why such a mistake apears .

```
//insert function just in case : 


template <typename T>
void List<T>::insert(const T& data, Iterator iterator=end()){
    if(iterator.list!=this){
        throw mtm::ListExceptions::ElementNotFound();
        return;
    }
    ListNode<T> *newNode = new ListNode<T>(data, iterator.current);
    if(iterator.index==size){
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            tail=newNode;
            }else{
        Iterator temp(this,size-1);
        temp.current->next=newNode;
            }
        //newNode->next=this->end().current;
           }
    else {
    if (head == NULL) {
    head = newNode;
    tail=newNode;
    }
   else {
       Iterator temp1(this,iterator.index-1);
        temp1.current->next=newNode;
        newNode->next=iterator.current->next;
   }

   }
    size++;
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller has the answer, but also, you're not allowed to define a default argument twice.  If `=end()` were a valid default argument, you'd get a compiler error about having it both in the declaration inside the class and in the member function definition outside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void insert(const T& data, Iterator iterator=end());
```

This is the offending line. A default argument cannot be the result of a member function call. The right tool to achieve what you want is overloading.

```
void insert(const T& data, Iterator iterator);
void insert(const T& data) { insert(data, end()); }
```

Here we still defer to the insert function you implemented, but we call `end` from within the overloads body, where it's allowed.

Don't worry about the indirect call. This is a very small function that's defined inside the class declaration itself. Any decent compiler will inline it completely.

Comment: so i tried this , but when i tried to to test this i got an error in the test : "insert is ambiguous candidates are : void insert(const int&) void insert(const int &,List<int>::Iterator)

Comment: @kasandra- You question was about *this particular error*. SO is not a forum where you get your entire program debugged for you. If you have another *specific* question, make another post.

Comment: @kasandra - I also fail to see how I'm supposed to know what's wrong with code I cannot examine. But I guess you did not remove the default argument from somewhere.

Comment: i tested irt like this in another cpp file : list.insert(5);

Comment: i know you are not a forum and you are a human but my question is still atached to the other problem of how to make the iterator default in the insert function.

Comment: @kasandra - The oveloading itself is not the problem, [see here](http://ideone.com/mQkucJ). You have an unrelated error in your code, like  aschepler pointed out in your post. You need to fix it. And I did not refer to myself when I said **SO** (as in, this site) is not a forum.

Comment: this is litrally almost the entire code .. i just added more functions that are not atached to all this but yeah this insert function just  makes the whole problems